# Is there a way to pass a variable to a generic view in Django?

Tags: django, generics, view

I am using Django's generic views and trying to find a way to filter a list of articles using D.R.Y.

My current `urls.py` file (only relevant section):

```
all_articles = {
    'queryset'      :   Article.objects.all(),
    'template_name' :   'article/admin.html'
}

url(r'^admin/$', object_list, all_articles, 'admin_article_home'),
```

I want do to something like the following, but without all the seemingly redundant code:

```
filter_status_draft = {
'queryset'      :   Article.objects.filter(status = 'Draft'),
'template_name' :   'article/admin.html'
}

filter_status_scheduled = {
'queryset'      :   Article.objects.filter(status = 'Scheduled'),
'template_name' :   'article/admin.html'
}

url(r'^admin/filter/status/draft/$', object_list, filter_status_draft, 'admin_article_status_filter_draft'),
url(r'^admin/filter/status/scheduled/$', object_list, filter_status_scheduled, 'admin_article_status_filter_scheduled'),
```

It seems there has to be a more efficient way to do this.

I have already viewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141673/generic-views-object-list-how-to-pass-request-variable), but it seems like creating a view defeats most of the purpose of a generic url.

Is there no way to do something as simple as this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write your own views, another way you could do this is by writing custom model managers. So you'd write you `urls.py` like:

```
filter_status_draft = {
    'queryset'      :   Article.objects.drafted(),
    'template_name' :   'article/admin.html'
}

filter_status_scheduled = {
    'queryset'      :   Article.objects.scheduled(),
    'template_name' :   'article/admin.html'
}
```

Check [documentation on writing custom model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for more info.

However, writing views, especially now when views are class-based, is a much more flexible and DRY approach in the long run.